# App crashes in case of available Reload, as many times as files to update

Tags: trigger.io

For each file that Reload has available, the app crashes 1 time, so if I have 5 changed files, I need to start the app 6 times before it works again, trace below:

```
Mar  6 16:33:55 ruben-iphone5 Forge[1633] <Warning>: [DEBUG] Linked reload file to existing assets file: splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png (f57416f87b40da8ea844d63636908eb1265739a8)
Mar  6 16:33:55 ruben-iphone5 Forge[1633] <Warning>: [INFO] We have 9 Reload files to download
Mar  6 16:33:58 ruben-iphone5 wifid[29] <Error>: WiFi:[384260638.130773]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"
Mar  6 16:33:58 ruben-iphone5 wifid[29] <Error>: WiFi:[384260638.142137]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"
Mar  6 16:33:58 ruben-iphone5 wifid[29] <Error>: WiFi:[384260638.781268]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"
Mar  6 16:34:01 ruben-iphone5 Forge[1633] <Warning>: [DEBUG] Downloaded reload file: assets/fonts/font-awesome/font-awesome.less (f3b7eab4f32ef629e684dff8353af6afaf6bd976)
Mar  6 16:34:01 ruben-iphone5 Forge[1633] <Error>: +[BorderControl returnResult:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x36c32c
Mar  6 16:34:01 ruben-iphone5 Forge[1633] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[BorderControl returnResult:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x36c32c'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x346103e7 0x3c301963 0x34613dc1 0x3461264d 0x3456a208 0x34f284a1 0x345e58f7 0x345e515d 0x345e3f2f 0x3455723d 0x345570c9 0x3813533b 0x364732b9 0xe4da7 0xe4d18)
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in our v1.4.32 platform version - thanks for bringing it to our attention!

I've just pushed a fix in v1.4.33: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-33

Comment: It still crashes 1 time every time there is a reload